# Can I create a txt file in python with name the string value of a variable?

Tags: python, file

i am trying to create a .txt python file in 3.0 version and as the name of the txt file will be the string value of date variable. Following code it creates a file but without .txt extension if I add .txt. in date.txt it gives me error.

```
date = str(input('Give me a date YY-MM-DD'))

f = open(date,'a')
f.write('Hello world')
f.close()
```

Comment: You probably want to name the file `date + '.txt'`

Comment: It worked, thank you!! f = open(date + '.txt','a')